# Horizontal line on display

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I have an HP Pavilion DV6 laptop which has a horizontal line on the display. I checked with an external monitor and the video was shown correctly, so I assume there is no problem with the GPU. The laptop's screen is new and I have changed the cable as well, but I am still having the same problem. Could someone please offer any advice?

Answer (score 5):

Changed the cable where? It's most likely an issue with the thin ribbon cable connecting the screen to the rest of the laptop in the hinge -- sometimes it snags and gets damaged. The horizontal line artifact you described occurs most often in this situation.

[image: LCD cable]

Comment: Usually you can find a replacement on a popular auction site for $10 or $15.